# jquery events not displaying in the right order

Tags: jquery, image, fadein, fadeout, attr

I am trying to make a function that fade out an image, then updates the sources of the img so when it fades back in it looks like a new img,
this is the code I have to do so:

```
var nextImg = function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        //get current img and next img
        var currentImg = $('.current-img-li');
        var nextImg = $('.current-img-li').next();        
        //check if is not last element
        if(nextImg.length === 0){
            //if it is the last img in the list go to the first img
            $('.big-img-img').fadeOut(750);
            $('.big-img-img').attr('src', '');
            console.log('fade out start');
            currentImg.removeClass('current-img-li');
            $('.img').first().addClass('current-img-li');
        }else{
            //go to the next img
            $('.big-img-img').fadeOut(750);
              $('.big-img-img').attr('src', '');
            currentImg.removeClass('current-img-li');
            nextImg.addClass('current-img-li'); 
        }
        //update the main img with the above source
        var selctedImg = $('.current-img-li').find('img').attr('src');
        $('.big-img-img').attr('src', selctedImg);
        $('.big-img-img').fadeIn(750);
    };
```

the issue I am having is the order of event should be 
1)fade out `.big-img-img`
2)update source of `.big-img-img`
3) fade `.big-img-img` back in
but the current events on my screen are:
1) update source
2) fade out
3) fade in
I have tried adding a delay to the update source but this doesn't fix it?
any ideas?

Comment: `fadeOut` etc. is async, but it does come with a callback, read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) !

Comment: so if I update the source in the callback function that should fix it? and what exactly do you mean by async?

Comment: btw.... that fixed it... thank you... if you want to put it as an official answer rather than a comment ill select it as an answer for you!